# AH02026: Failed to acquire SSL session cache lock

Tags: apache, ssl, locking

First post, apologies if I get anything wrong.

Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS 7)

I am seeing repeated warnings in the ssl_error_logs of many of my virtual hosts. The warnings are:

[ssl:warn] [pid 8995] (22)Invalid argument: AH02027: Failed to release SSL session cache lock

[ssl:warn] [pid 8997] (22)Invalid argument: AH02026: Failed to acquire SSL session cache lock

If I restart httpd these errors go away for up to a few days but then re-appear.

I have read around this issue but can find no solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the `APACHE_RUN_USER` is used for SSH login purposes too. Then, `systemd` clears all the locks of the user during logout, including the locks used by Apache 2.

The solution is to prevent `systemd` from removing the locks by adding the following line to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
RemoveIPC=no
```

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't worked. Still getting lines like:

[Mon Dec 13 09:32:10.222900 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 27922] (22)Invalid argument: AH02027: Failed to release SSL session cache lock

here's my login.conf

#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
RemoveIPC=no
#UserTasksMax=

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and aren't even using systemd (sysV here). related issue: https://serverfault.com/q/856561/182307